# Is it possible to find which specific index entry fails texindy?

Tags: errors, indexing, xindy

I have a document which causes the following error in `texindy`:

> Processing index...
>
> WARNING: Would replace complete index key by empty string, ignoring # '' :again NIL>
>
> ERROR: CHAR: index 0 should be less than the length of the string

When I look through the `.idx` file I cannot see any entries with zero length.

When I search the source document for `\index{}` there are none.

Without knowing where in the about 1 MB document there is an invalid index entry it is impossible to fix. How can I troubleshoot further?

I tried different debug arguments on the command line to `texindy` but there is no increased amount of verbosity in the output, no extra log files, and no way to determine what specifically the program does not like.